# Do Photons Really "Exist" as Particles?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, photons, spacetime, field-theory

[Major Edit Begins]

My question below (which I leave in for posterity) has fairly been flagged for clarification which I shall attempt while trying to include the information already received.

If an event causes an electron to give up a quanta of energy to the EM field as a spread distribution of potentiality (probability function) and that this energy can then be transferred by the EM field (obeying the probability function) to another particle, in what sense do we need to posit the existence of a photon as a particle at all other than to describe the effect we observe (energy being transferred from one discreet system to another at a distance)? Is it true to say that a "photon in transit" is merely a mathematical construct representing the energy exchange performed probabilistically by the EM field allowing us to do meaningful calculations?

I sense that even this is poorly worded and yet can think of no other way (from my relevant ignorance) to make myself any clearer.

[Major Edit Ends]

Assuming that Special Relativity is correct then it can be demonstrated that photons do not experience space or time due to the effects of dilation and contraction. For a photon, it's "birth" when emitted is indistinguishable in time to it's "death" when it is absorbed. Similarly, the photon travels zero distance which requires time to traverse. If no time passes then no distance can be travelled. How then do photons propagate throughout the universe?

We can say that an object is moving by stating that when the object is at rest before starting it's journey at time t0 the object has travelled distance d0 and is now at position p0. Then, as it begins to move, at time t1 the object has travelled distance d1 and is now at position p1. This continues for t2, t3, t4, t5 etc all the way to the end of the path that the object takes through space-time. However, this can not be the case for a photon. If it experiences zero time and zero space then it can have no position p1, p2, p3 etc as this would require the photon to experience both time and distance.

Can this mean that photons simply do not "exist"? By "exist" I mean be manifestly present in space-time. What if a photon is simply a potential quantised state of energy which can only be measured, or said to "exist" when it interacts with another particle? Could it be that it is not the photon which is "moving" but only it's potential to become manifest. Is the thing that is actually travelling through space-time merely the photon's probability function? Is it possible that the wavelength of any given photon does not exist and can in no way be measured until it interacts with another particle?

Could this in anyway be elucidated upon by using Feynman diagrams? Does it have anything to say about quantum super-position or entanglement? Does it have any bearing upon the strange results  of the double slit experiment. Other questions come to mind. Does the photon "know" where it's destination will be even at the very moment of transmission and does this say anything about the block universe theory and therefore the nature of the future? (not to mention what this means for the whole notion of free will).

It is at this point that I start to get in over my head and find myself in territory that is way above my pay grade. But if any of this makes sense to anyone else out there, even if it's all complete nonsense, does it provide any incite or concept that has not already been rigorously investigated and included in our current scientific understanding? (Please bear in mind that I only possess a basic high-school level of knowledge mixed with much consumption of popular science books and videos)

TL;DR

Can it be said that photons do not exist in any way, shape or form in space-time and can only be expressed in terms of probabilities of becoming actualised after "emission" and before "absorption"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46465/discussion-on-question-by-captfrantic-do-photons-really-exist-as-particles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why CaptFrantic is getting a lot of downvotes for this question. When he says:

> I'm suggesting that the particle notion (after "emission" but before
>   "absorption") is at best misleading and meaningless and at at worst
>   possibly wholly incorrect.

isn't he on pretty solid ground? I'm not sure if I find his relativistic argument convincing, but surely nobody who knows anything about these things actually believes that photons exist in between emission and absorption as discrete concentrated particles of energy?

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. I was also wondering this very thing and am tempted to write a rant post suggesting that in 1904 Einstein would have been laughed out of here for suggesting that he could do a thought experiment where he rode a photon to see what happened. I won't do that of course, partly because I've just vented and no longer feel the need :D. Thanks again.

Comment: You are just speculating.  We don't know why there are down votes.  In particular, we have no evidence at all that the down votes are a result of one or another interpretation of what a photon is.  So this answer gets a down vote from me.

Comment: So this is the accepted answer?  Then I completely misinterpreted the question.  (tl;dr)  If the germ of the argument is that photon are not particles, then I'm on board.

Comment: garyp, I nominated this answer as "correct" only insofar as I found it the most helpful. I agree that my question was poorly framed but yes, a large part of my post had to do with my assertion that photons do not exist as particles while "travelling" through space-time.

Answer (score 1):

Quanta of the electromagnetic field certainly exist in *my* frame of reference. If I understand your argument, you are saying that the proper time between generation and destruction of a photon is zero in its own frame of reference, and one way to understand this oddity is to posit that photons don't exist at all.

The problem is that the frame of reference of a photon does not exist.  Or at the very least, special relativity has nothing to say about it if it does exist.  Considering such a thing is outside the bounds of special relativity.  There is no meaning to "proper time in the reference frame of the photon".

Special relativity *can* tell me that if a photon exists in my frame, then it exists in every frame.

Comment: To be clear (although I admit that my question was poorly framed which can surely be forgiven) I am not saying that the "photon" does not exist at all. I'm merely speculating that it does not exist in the traditional sense that we are lead to believe that they exist, ie as a particle/wave duality that travels through space-time. I'm suggesting that the particle notion (after "emission" but before "absorption") is at best misleading and meaningless and at at worst possibly wholly incorrect. My position and train of thought can be more clearly examined in my conversation with Jim above.

Answer (score -1):

Photons (massless particles in vacuum) exist from the point of view of the reference frame of observers. In contrast, the lightlike spacetime interval between their place of emission A and their place of absorption B is zero (empty). That means, from an absolute point of view, photons don't exist, they are just transmission of momentum between two adjacent points A and B, similar to collisions between two particles which are adjacent at the moment of the collision.

However from the point of view of observers, the points A and B are not adjacent, and they observe an electromagnetic wave as a sort of "placeholder" in the space between the two points which does not correspond to any spacetime interval.

Edit: This is not an issue of different "time stages", but there are two complementary descriptions which are both valid. On one hand the description of the observed photon (remember that the second postulate of SR says that c is the velocity of light *as measured by any observer*), and on the other hand the invariant description of the spacetime interval of a photon which does not correspond to any measurement.

Comment: Thank-you. This concurs with my current understanding and my way of thinking about "photons" as being waves while "travelling" and only becoming particle-like when they interact with other particles.

Comment: Se  my edit above.

Comment: I saw the edit and can still find no point of disagreement.

Comment: Downvoter - why ?

Comment: Moonraker - funnily enough I find myself asking the same question ...